# How to use filereader in Svelte

Tags: svelte, filereader

I am trying to use the javascript *FileReader* in a Svelte project but I cannot get the *onload* method to function. What am I doing wrong?

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ba454ebb53764feabf176459bf295be3?version=3.52.0)

```
    <input id="upload-file" type="file" accept=".txt" on:change={uploadArchive}>

    <script>        
        async function uploadArchive() {
            const reader = new FileReader()
            console.log('before load');
            reader.onload = function () {
                console.log('after load');
            };
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why do you want to read the file? `uploadArchive` sounds like you want to upload it, if so, there isn't any need to read the file first.

Comment: Upload because after processing it will be passed to an API

Comment: If the processing is done client-side it can be circumvented. You might want to not do that and move it to the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`onload` is an event callback that will fire once the file has been successfully read. When the event is fired, the [`FileReader.result`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result) will contain the data.

You need to call one of the methods that actually loads the file:

- `readAsArrayBuffer()`
- `readAsBinaryString()`
- `readAsDataURL()`
- `readAsText()`

It depends on what you want to do with the file.

You can get the file to pass as an argument from the event object.

```js
async function uploadArchive(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file == null)
        return; // If user cancels file selection

    // rest of code
}
```

---

Note that you do not necessarily even need a `FileReader`. The `File` object has asychronous functions for reading it in various formats through its `Blob` prototype ([browser support info](https://caniuse.com/?search=Blob.text)). So you could just do:

```js
async function uploadArchive(e) {
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    if (file == null)
        return; // If user cancels file selection

    const text = await file.text();
}
```